# DataGridView in winforms application && List of structs

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, collections, datagridview

I'm using a `DataGridView` control in my winforms application

```
  private struct Ligne
        {
            public string Jour;
            public string LaDate;
            public int Heures;
            public int Minutes;
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
            openfile.Filter = "fichier texte (*.txt)|*.txt";
            if (openfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox2.Text = openfile.FileName;
                List<Ligne> str = ParsingFile(textBox2.Text);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = str;
            }
        }
```

As you can see, i'm trying to bind a list of structs as a datasource of the grid, but i got empty fields even the listt isn't empty :

[image: demo]

I need to know:

- Why the grid is empty?
- How can fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make the fields of your list Properties like this:

```
public string Jour; { get; set; }
public string LaDate; { get; set; }
public int Heures; { get; set; }
public int Minutes; { get; set; }
```

..or else their values can't be accessed.

I assume that the Columns get created OK.